# Custom Cursor Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-cursor

I'm currently developing my Website and I have Implemented a Custom Cursor with CSS and JS But the problem I'm facing is that the Custom Cursor is animated and it does animate on the first link but doesn't on the others links on the website I even tried adding specific classes, Id, directly getting them by their tags but it doesn't seem to work If anyone could help that would be so nice of you.

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
let mouseCursor2 = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
let hover = document.querySelector("a");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor);

function cursor(e){
   mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px",
   mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
   mouseCursor2.style.top = e.pageY + "px",
   mouseCursor2.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
}


$(hover).hover(function() {
    hover.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
        mouseCursor.classList.remove("hover"),
        mouseCursor2.classList.remove("hide");
    });
    hover.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        mouseCursor.classList.add("hover"),
        mouseCursor2.classList.add("hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: please add the code in the post you are working on. It will help us to understand your problem and provide you solution.

Comment: I Added the Js code hope it can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only selects single node (the first node that matches the selector).

use `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to select all the elements matching the selector.

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
let mouseCursor2 = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
let hover = document.querySelectorAll("a");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor);

function cursor(e){
   mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px",
   mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
   mouseCursor2.style.top = e.pageY + "px",
   mouseCursor2.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
}


hover.forEach(el => {

    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
        mouseCursor.classList.remove("hover"),
        mouseCursor2.classList.remove("hide");
    });

    el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        mouseCursor.classList.add("hover"),
        mouseCursor2.classList.add("hide");
    });
})
```

Comment: no worries @OutdatedDNZ . if the solution works for you. make sure to accept answer.

Comment: Im also facing this weird problem with the cursor which is when I hover at a link at the first time the style doesn't apply but does when I hover over it the second time.

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ I have updated the code. it should work correctly now.

Comment: ALSO please please can you hellp me with another thing??

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ I am no GOD, just an average developer.  Glad I Could help you.

Comment: If it is not related to this one then you should post another question for another thing. I will try me best to answer it.

Comment: Its related sort of cause its the cursor thing as well so I wanted to add delay to the bigger cursor and I did by add transition property to it in the CSS file but it is very staggered. Can you help me for the last time please

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ I am not very good with css transitions ... I suggest you to post another question ... I am sure someone will help you out.